# Cant get angular strap DatePicker to work

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I have tried all I can but cant seem to get my datepicker to work.
I tried to use it like this :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer" readonly="readonly" data-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" data-max-date="{{item.ReturnDate}}" ng-model="item.DepartDate" placeholder="From" bs-datepicker />
```

here is a  fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/a0tzLvaL/1/  created with the issue.

Comment: Check the console, there are 3 errors at least.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. i didn't create that fiddle correctly.
I tried to delete this but cant :/.
I did post another question though.
This append after i upgraded to the newest version of angular strap from 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was that after upgrading that you cannot use readonly,
once i removed that i was a for away